# VBA - Copying & pasting from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and my knowledge is currently limited to recording basic macros. I am trying to figure out how to automate a pretty straight forward process. We get the same type of data on a monthly basis, which I need to take and feed in directly to a pre-existing model which then spits out a number, let's call it "Profit". Sometimes the data may come in a SS which is named slightly different to previous months or it may have additional tabs in the SS but the fundamental data which I need will never change. I will always need to take cells B2:Y26 from the tab "ProfCalc" then manually paste it in the model.

I found the following code from a similar question asked in the past but it's not quite working to my specific problem.

```
Sub Profit()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("B2:Y26").Value = x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("B2:Y26") 

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

How do I set up the macro so that the filepath is automatically updated with the specific template which I may have open? The data which I'm copying will always be in the same format but it won't be in the same folder, as I will need to generate this for multiple different clients.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: So the first issue I'm having is that the workbook path doesn't seem to be recognised. I've taken a copy of the entire UNC path and the code is just red and won't run. The second problem I can perceive occuring is that the workbook which I'm copying the data from will not automatically update with the correct name and path. Think this might be a problem as I will need to run this for quite a few different clients and the template which I need to copy and then paste in the model is saved in their respective folders.

Comment: I suggest you add that to the question. Hard to say without seeing the path. Have you tried recording a macro of opening the file?

Comment: So the reason why it wasn't originally working was because I was using apostophes instead of quotation marks. Still struggling to figure out a solution for the second part though. Do you think it's probably best to set up a control table, whereby I can input the relevant UNC path and then just use an indirect function to open it up? Something like this: 
Runs FilePath
1 K:\Client1\ProfitCalc.xlsx
2 K:\Client2\ProfitCalc.xlsx
3 K:\Client3\ProfitCalc.xlsx
4 K:\Client4\ProfitCalc.xlsx

Comment: If you have a list of valid paths then a loop over that list would seem a good approach. If the actual file path(s) are unknown then that's a different story and you'd need to describe how you'd determine manually which is the file you want, then try to transform that process to VBA.